# Function is raising 'StaleElementReferenceException' when output of other function is passed as an argument

Tags: python, selenium, python-tesseract

In Python, I have created two function one of which extracts text from an image(using pytesseract) and other uses the same text as an argument to make a Google search(using selenium).

Both the functions work normally if both are called separately(which is not desirable) in same program. When I am manually passing any string in the function that makes Google search, it works absolutely fine, program terminates normally.No problem in extracting text.

But when I pass the returned value from the other function which is extracting text from image(which is essential), the same function which was working fine, raises "StaleElementReferenceException". The exception raises after the text is extracted from image, passed to other function and the search is made in the browser.

How to avoid this ?

This is my whole code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import time
from selenium import webdriver


# extracts text from image
def convert_to_text(path):
    image = Image.open(path)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config=' ')
    return text


# makes a google search
def get_result(search_term):
    url = "https://www.google.com/"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
    browser.get(url)
    search_box = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.quit()


var = convert_to_text('C:/Users/Gaurav/Desktop/Capture.png')
get_result(var)
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gaurav\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\ocr.py", line 25, in <module>
    get_result(var)
  File "C:\Users\Gaurav\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\ocr.py", line 19, in get_result
    search_box.submit()
  File "C:\Users\Gaurav\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 85, in submit
    form = self.find_element(By.XPATH, "./ancestor-or-self::form")
  File "C:\Users\Gaurav\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 658, in find_element
    return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\Gaurav\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Gaurav\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Gaurav\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score -1):

This exception occurs when you've navigated to another page different from where you defined the element. I think because the JIT compiler, and the fact you navigate to a different url in `get_result()` causes the stale element reference.

The only way I can think to avoid this is to define the element and use it in the same function. I know that's not ideal, perhaps someone else can think of a better way...